# Python kivy update a variable from a class to another on on_press

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language, kivymd

I got here a simple code, but I don't remember how to update the **set_value** variable from the method **average** in the class **KomagomaApp** by pressing on the button in **MainWidget** in the .kv file. Can't find the solution anywhere.
Thank you for your help.

```
class CircularProgressBarMath(AnchorLayout):
    set_value = 0

class CircularProgressBarPhysic(AnchorLayout):
    set_value = 75

class CircularProgressBarChemistry(AnchorLayout):
    set_value = 65

class MainWidget(Widget):
    pass

class KomagomaApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return MainWidget()

    def average(self):
        pass
```

And the .kv file:

```
<CircularProgressBarMath>:
    canvas.before:
        Color:
            rgb: (0.329, 0.298, 0.263)
        Line:
            width: 1.3
            ellipse: (self.x, self.y, self.width, self.height, 0, 270)

    canvas.after:
        Color:
            rgb: (0.827, 0.737, 0.557)
        Line:
            id: progress_bar_math
            width: 2.3
            ellipse: (self.x, self.y, self.width, self.height, 0, root.set_value*2.7)

<MainWidget>:
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'horizontal'
        size: root.width, root.height
        padding: 50

        BoxLayout:
            orientation: 'vertical'
            size_hint: 1, 1
            padding: 20

            AnchorLayout:
                anchor_x: 'center'
                size_hint: 1, 1

                Button:
                    text: '+'
                    font_size: '20px'
                    pos_hint: {'top': 0.1, 'right': 1}
                    size_hint: 0.1, 0.1
                    on_release: app.average()

                CircularProgressBarMath:
                    size_hint: None, None
                    size: 500, 500
                    pos_hint: {'center_x': 0.5, 'center_y': 0.5}

                CircularProgressBarPhysic:
                    size_hint: None, None
                    size: 420, 420
                    pos_hint: {'center_x': 0.5, 'center_y': 0.5}

                CircularProgressBarChemistry:
                    size_hint: None, None
                    size: 340, 340
                    pos_hint: {'center_x': 0.5, 'center_y': 0.5}
```

I tried multiple things I saw here but no way to make it works.

Comment: You have three different `set_value` variables in your code. which one are you trying to update?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you have to inform Kivy that 'set_value' is Kivy's widget property type.

```
from kivy.properties import NumericProperty

class CircularProgressBarMath(AnchorLayout):
    set_value = NumericProperty(0)  # instead of: set_value = 0
```

Then specify id for your custom widget instance within kv file:

```
CircularProgressBarMath:
    id: my_bar
```

Now you can modify your widget's property as usual. Your widget will be updated automatically on property change:

```
def average(self):
    self.root.ids.my_bar.set_value += 5
```

Comment: I had to adapt the solution but it works! Thank you! w

Answer (score 0):

Give `id` to your custom widgets and use it.

```
CircularProgressBarMath:
    id: first_bar
    size_hint: None, None
    size: 500, 500
    pos_hint: {'center_x': 0.5, 'center_y': 0.5}
```

In your average function:

```py
def build(self):
    # Save the main widget as a class variable
    self.root = MainWidget()
    return self.root

def average(self):
    self.root.ids.first_bar.set_value = 123
```